# No Scheme to select in Google Fabric Configure Project

Tags: google-fabric

I'm trying to distribute a beta build of an iOS xCode/Swift app using Crashlytics/Fabric/Fastlane 2.66.0.
I get to "Distribute your project" and successfully select the project.
It then offers a dropdown under Scheme "Select scheme to build" but the dropdown doesn't open, so I have no way forward.
(Obviously I'm new to this - a refugee from Windows 10)

Comment: In Xcode, when you select Product -> Scheme -> Manage Scheme, do you see a scheme listed? If not, select "Autocreate Schemes Now"

Comment: I have re-started Fabric and it's taken me back to rebuilding the project which has opened the app  in the simulator and taken me back to the Fabric screen:
Crashlytics 3.9.3
Force a Crash....
User Information...
So I'm totally confused.

Comment: Press the arrow in the top left of the Fabric app from the screen you're on and then you get press the fastlane icon.

Comment: Apologies, but I'm totally confused.

Comment: I open Fabric inwhich I have fastlane 2,66,2 installed.
Distribute Beta Builds: Get Started
It checks fastlane installed - gets a tick
I click on "2 Configure Your Project >"
"Project/Workspace: Select project..\/" Click
It displays a list of my projects, and I select the one I want to distribute
"Scheme: Select scheme to build \/" 
I click on the \/ but there's no response.

Comment: And yes,Product -> Scheme -> Manage Scheme displays three schemes in my project: {app name}, {app name} WatchKit App and {app name} WatchKitApp (Complication)

Comment: When I check the boxes under "Shared", Fabric now shows me the three schemes - this is SO obscure to the new user!
But which scheme do I distribute? I want the complete app - phone,  watch app and complication to be distributed.